# Number of Plane Oriented Recursive Trees

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

The number of plane oriented recursive trees is $(2n-3)!!$

I understand that given a vertex $v$ with $k$ successors, there are $k+1$ ways to attach a new vertex to create a new tree of size one bigger than before. So then if there are $n$ vertices in the tree there should be $2n-3$ ways to attach another vertex, but I don't follow this step.

My thinking was that for each vertex you have "number of succesors"+1 possibilities for attachment, i.e. $\sum_{v \in V}(d^+(v)+1) = 2n-1$, for V the vertices in the tree at the moment, $d^+(v)$ the number of successors of $v$ and $n =|V|$. It seems like I'm overcounting, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're counting right – it's just that the last tree that you attach a new vertex to is the one with $n-1$ vertices, not the one with $n$ vertices – thus the last factor is $2(n-1)-1=2n-3$. See also [this treatment](https://books.google.de/books?id=j3kZBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA317&lpg=PA317&dq=number%20of%20plane%20oriented%20recursive%20trees&source=bl&ots=X-7aycW_j9&sig=3LwUZmgTNHN8qMAUff2rKnY_9z0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOgpHT7rPLAhWCjXIKHfg8AS04ChDoAQgmMAI#v=onepage&q=number%20of%20plane%20oriented%20recursive%20trees&f=false).

Comment: Aaah! Well that makes me feel a lot better, thank you!!